# Exit Try/Catch to prevent code after from being run

Tags: c#

I've got for example a try/catch in my method:

```
    }
    catch (OurCustomExceptionObject1 ex)
    {
       txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 1";
    }
    catch(OurCustomExceptionObject2 ex)
    {
        txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 2";
    }
    catch (OurCustomExceptionObject3 ex)
    {
        txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 3";
    }

    ... rest of code here is being executed after the try/catch
```

I do not want the rest of code to run if any of the exceptions are caught.  I'm handling the exceptions.  I heard do not use Exit Try for some reason.  Is that true, it's bad to do this?  Is this the right way to halt execution of code thereafter the catch statement?

Comment: `Exit Try` exists only in VB.NET. It doesn't apply to C#. In C#, the corresponding language feature would be `break`, but that's illegal in a `try..catch..finally` block. The next best thing would be `return`, which doesn't do the same, but is a perfectly legal thing to do.

Comment: @stakx `break` is not illegal in `catch` block. It can be used to break out of the loop.

Comment: @stakx: The workaround for no `Exit Try` Statement in C#.net (vs. VB.NET) is to wrap the `try` Statement inside a `while (true) { ... break; }` Statement and then use `break` (vs. `Exit Try` Statements).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Either `return` in the catch-block, rethrow the exception, or move the code from below the try-block inside the try-block.

Comment: Precisely what I was going to answer

Comment: Yep. And I think moving the code is the best approach in this case. If you want to stop the code from continuing when there's an exception - do nothing. An exception already interrupts the execution flow. Just surround the whole thing with a try-catch if you want to handle the operation too. Although if it's a method, I'd surround the method call rather than the method body, so exceptions aren't swallowed unintentionally.

Comment: yes that's true. but in my case the rest of the code so much. is it ok to put a bulk of code in a try statement? because then every catch in that part will be caught under the one catch in the end and for example i will not be able to which exception refers to where.

Answer (score 2):

Two options immediately come to mind:

1. `return` straight from inside each `catch` (as BlueRaja suggested)
2. set a flag (e.g., `errorOccurred`) within the `catch` blocks for the exceptions you don't want to allow, then put `if (errorOccurred) return;` after the whole try/catch block

The latter *might* be more readable to other developers, since it's easy to skim past what happens inside a `catch` to figure out what happens afterward. Seeing a blatant `if (errorOccurred) return;` makes it pretty hard to misunderstand what happened.

Answer (score 1):

From a high level view, I think this could be a violation of (at least) the Single Responsibility Principle if your code is trying to do something that could fail, and then go on to do some more stuff.

For the sake of an answer though, if you wanted to do a hack (which is always bad, so don't) you could do

```
bool success = true;
try
{
    // the good ol' college try
}
catch (...)
{
    success = false;
}

if (success)
{
    // do the rest of your stuff
}
```

**edit:** or alternatively as BlueRaja suggested, put *all* of your code into the try block. If the first bit fails, it fails. The rest of the code won't run anyway.

Comment: I don't know about that.  It all depends on the situation and logic that needs to take place.  I don't see why processing after would hurt anything if all you're doing to handle expected errors is by logging and moving onto the next code in the method after the catch.

Answer (score 1):

How to do a VB Exit Try:

```
try {
   for(;;) {
      if( x>y ) break;  // forced exit try

      ....

      break; // natural exit try, must be present
   }
}
catch {
...
} 
finally {
...
}
```

Comment: This is a rather old question an have accepted answer that didn't use a workaround (for() /break)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, like ilMes above. Just more complete.

```
   do
    {
        try
        {    
         //do try something ...
        }
        catch (OurCustomExceptionObject1 ex)
        {
           txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 1";
           break;
        }
        catch(OurCustomExceptionObject2 ex)
        {
            txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 2";
            break;
        }
        catch (OurCustomExceptionObject3 ex)
        {
            txtErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "test 3";
            break;
        }
        
        UnwantedFunctionIfCatchIsTriggered();//this code won't run if break is called
    }while(false)
     
    //wanted code continues.
```